# Ajax sending isaute

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send some data to save.php in order to save it in db.
The thing is: Ajax post i success and it's returning right data in a console but 'echo' in save.php is returning nothing.I don't know what's wrong with this code.

```
var $nick = $('span.nick').html(); 
var $scores = points;
var range = n2;
var $upgrades =
    {
        'numbers': range,
        'pointsPerSec': pps,
        'multip': multi
    };


    //Save to DB
    $.ajax({
        url: "save.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            userID: $nick,
            userPoints: $scores,
            userUpgrades: $upgrades
        },
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function(){
            alert('Data saved');
            console.log(save);
            getData();
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('You fucked up mate :(');
        }
    });



function getData(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'save.php',
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            data = $.parseJSON(data);
            $.each(data, function(i, save){
                console.log(save);
            });
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('Error Ajax');
        }
    });
}
```

Here's my save.php file

```
if(isset($_POST['userPoints']) && !empty($_POST['userPoints'])){
     $post=$_POST["userPoints"] or $_REQUEST["userPoints"];
     $dec_post=json_decode($post);
     echo $dec_post;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you did not passed any parameter in your ajax success function, to retrive and console data in success function you should pass a parameter in the success change your ajax success function as

```
success: function(response){
    alert('Data saved');
    console.log(response);
    getData();
},
```

Comment: It's returning 0.
What should I do?

Comment: @LastShadowPL check your php script, i don't think it is using the right syntax to assign value in $post variable

Answer (score 0):

found your mistake:

```
if(isset($_POST['userPoints']) && !empty($_POST['userPoints']))
        {
            $post = $_POST["userPoints"] or $_REQUEST["userPoints"];
            $dec_post = json_encode($post); // mistake was here
            echo $dec_post;
// you should exit; or die; here if this is final response
        }
```

success callback has a response arg
you were missing that

```
//Save to DB
$.ajax({
    url: "save.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        userID: $nick,
        userPoints: $scores,
        userUpgrades: $upgrades
    },
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    success: function(save){
        alert('Data saved');
        console.log(save);
        getData();
    },
    error: function(){
        alert('You fucked up mate :(');
    }
});
```

Comment: It's returning 0

Comment: console is returning right response but when I open save.php (via <a> on main page) it says "undefined index"  e.g. "Notice: Undefined index: userID in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Strony/gierczak/save.php on line 16" same with the others. saving function is binded to click.Should it be submit or what?

Comment: And it's echoing 'null'

Comment: line 16: $nick = $_POST['userID'];

Comment: post bit more of save.php

Answer (score 0):

Here's save.php

```
session_start();
    /*if(!isset($_SESSION['loggined'])&&($_SESSION['loggined']==true)) {
        header('location: index.php');
        exit();
    }*/
    require_once "dbconnect.php";
    $connect= @new mysqli($host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
    if($connect->connect_errno != 0){
        die("There was an error");
    }
    else
    {
            $nick = $_POST['userID'] or $_REQUEST["userID"];
            $enNick = json_encode($nick);
            echo $enNick;


        $points = $_POST['userPoints'] or $_REQUEST["userPoints"];
        $enPoints = json_encode($points);
        echo $enPoints;

        $upgrades = $_POST['userUpgrades'] or $_REQUEST["userUpgrades"];
        $enUpgrades = json_encode($upgrades);
        echo $enUpgrades;

$connect->close();
```